# LUA - Get Variable from Callback

Tags: function, http, lua, callback

I'm new at LUA coding and have the first problem:

I try to make a http.get request and want to get the content to a variable. Here is my code:

```
local API_KEY = ""

function getAPIKey()
    local key
    http.get(SERVER_URL .. "?query=getapikey&mac=" .. wifi.ap.getmac(), 
        function(code, data)
            if(code < 0) then
                print("HTTP request failed")
            else
                key = data
            end
        end)
    print(key)
end
```

When I try this code i'll get an error because the vaiable `API_KEY` is `nil`.

Does anybody hava some ideas?

Comment: you have never assigned your API_KEY. where are you trying to use it?

Comment: Perhaps you want `local key = http.get(...)`.

Comment: i have the exact same issue right now, imo the key is always nil because the http.get callback function is called much later. so the question would be something like: how to fetch the value of a callback function. did anyone found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem 1: You aren't gathering the body that http.get() returns, thus printing an empty local variable.

Maybe problem 2: `API_KEY` is unused in your code, so it won't have any affect on anything. However, `API_KEY = ""` (dropping the local) to make it global may have an affect on some library already loaded - in this case whatever you got http.get from. You might need to look up the documentation if this is the case/get an API key from the API (usually used to prevent just anyone from using the API).

Maybe problem 3: I have one concern, though, and its `code < 0` in the anonymous function. Usually http will return a `code > 0` (unsigned): `200` means OK, `404` means not found, `403` means forbidden, and anything in the `300`'s has to do with redirects, which may require more work from you. See [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for http code reference. Perhaps the data returned via the function is actually the expected data. If this is the case (and you'll know by the error codes), then I would remove `key = data` for `print(data)`.

Possible solution 1:

```
-    local API_KEY = ""
+    API_KEY = ""
```

Possible solution 2:

```
function getAPIKey()
-   local key
-   http.get(SERVER_URL .. "?query=getapikey&mac=" .. wifi.ap.getmac(),
+   local key = http.get(SERVER_URL .. "?query=getapikey&mac=" .. wifi.ap.getmac(),
        function(code, data)
            if(code < 0) then
                print("HTTP request failed")
            else
                key = data
            end
        end)
    print(key)
end
```

Debug solution 1:

```
function getAPIKey()
    local key
    http.get(SERVER_URL .. "?query=getapikey&mac=" .. wifi.ap.getmac(),
    local key = http.get(SERVER_URL .. "?query=getapikey&mac=" .. wifi.ap.getmac(),
        function(code, data)
            if(code < 0) then
-               print("HTTP request failed")
+               print("HTTP request failed!", "`" .. code .. "`")
+               print("data:", "`" .. data .. "`")
            else
+               print(code, "`" .. data .. "`")
                key = data
            end
        end)
    print(key)
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your very detailed explanation. I've tryed both possible solutions, but I still get the same error even if I try to make an output at the end of the function.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: http.get will  always return nil so this solution can not work..